# Django REST framework non-model serializer and BooleanField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I seem to have hit a wall full of puzzling results when trying to deal with the following use case:

```
URL: '^api/event/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/registration$'
payload: {"registered": "true"} or {"registered": "false"}
```

I retrieve the event object corresponding to the given pk, and then based on that I want:

- in a GET request to retrieve whether the authenticated user is registered or not
- in a PUT to change the registration state.

Everything works fine until the point where I want to process the incoming payload in the PUT request. I've tried creating a serializer like this:

```
class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    registered = fields.BooleanField()
```

and call it from an APIView's put method with:

```
serializer = RegistrationSerializer(data=request.DATA)
```

but it doesn't work and `serializer.data` always contains `{"registered": False}

From a shell I tried another isolated test:

```
>>> rs = RegistrationSerializer(data={'registered':True})
>>> rs
<app.serializers.RegistrationSerializer object at 0x10a08cc10>
>>> rs.data
{'registered': False}
```

What am I doing wrong? What would be the best way to handle this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `rs.is_valid()` first, before accessing `rs.data`.

Really the framework ought to raise an exception if you don't do so.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks Tom. I checked again the documentation and indeed in the "Validation" section it is stated that one should always call the `.is_valid()` method, but I had completely missed it.